# Walker on edge of pixel-based shapes

Tags: algorithm, graph, pixel, shapes

I want to create a walker that walks around any shape. the shape can be either pixel color in a matrix or selected edges on a graph. the walker have two functions one is determine the next step and the second is move to the next step. The walker starts on some point that adjacent to the shape and has a general direction to where to go (clockwise or counter-clockwise)

[image]

Any tips on how should I tackle that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tip: if you're going clockwise, keep your right hand on the shape.

Which means that the code needs to keep track of the orientation of the walker. In the example, the walker is initially facing north (assuming north at the top, and east to the right). After one step, the walker is still facing north.

The orientation of the walker determines the order in which the code should check for the next valid move as shown in the table below:

| orientation | directions to check |
| --- | --- |
| north | east, north, west, south |
| east | south, east, north, west |
| south | west, south, east, north |
| west | north, west, south, east |

So the walker must be given a starting location, a clockwise/counter-clockwise indication, and an initial orientation.

Comment: thank you. that was enough to make me understand. this is easier than I thought. I ended up checking around the current full block (defined to be the 'anchor') clockwise. if the place im checking is empty than go there. else than this is the new anchor block and keep checking.